# No module named flask.ext.restful

Tags: python, flask

trying to run a server

```
    (dal)➜  Server (master) python mainDAL.py                                                        ✭ ✱
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "mainDAL.py", line 4, in <module>
        from flask.ext import restful
      File "/Users/partuck/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 87, in load_module
        raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.restful
```

my pip include Flask with the latest version. what I don't understand is what is this what is this restful module.

read here http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#id1
that it exists.

```
 (dal)➜  Server (master) pip freeze                                                               ✭ ✱
Flask==0.10.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
mimerender==0.5.4
pbr==0.10.7
pipdeptree==0.4.2
pymongo==2.7.2
python-dateutil==2.4.0
python-mimeparse==0.1.4
six==1.9.0
SQLAlchemy==0.9.8
stevedore==1.2.0
virtualenv==12.0.5
virtualenv-clone==0.2.5
virtualenvwrapper==4.3.2
Werkzeug==0.9.6
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have installed Flask, but you haven't installed `Flask-RESTful`, it's not in your `pip freeze` list.

You can [install](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.1/installation.html) it with `pip install flask-restful`.

Answer (score 4):

I just met similar problem, My native language is not english, in that tutorial, it said uses flask restful by `from flask.ext import restful`, but it will throw out `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask.ext'`.

Finally in [Flask-RESTful: english version Tutorial](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-api),

It shows the correct usage `from flask_restful import Resource, Api`.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem and above code was unable to solve my problem. You can directly apply the below code:-

```
pip install Flask-API
```

This will help you install Flask-API and you don't need to individually update/load modules.

Answer (score 3):

first to install flask-restful api use command:

```
pip install flask-restful
```

And import the package flask_restful,such as:

```
from flask_restful import Resource,reqparse, Api
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What new information or insight has your answer provided that the other answers have not *already* provided?

Comment: your answer worked for me... i was using an old repo that referenced `from flask.ext.restful...` and switching to `from flask_restful import ...` fixed the issue!